# What is the use of barcode in php?

Tags: php, gd

I have seen a lot of tutorials and articles showing how to generate barcode with Php using Gd library and Pear. But frankly saying i have no idea what is the use of generating them.

Like in retail stores barcodes are printed on a paper to scan and get details of a particular product. But what is the use of barcodes on the web ?

Thanks

Comment: The question is off topic, but I assume they're for apps that generate printable things (invoices, product catalogues, stickers...)

Comment: Just a guess. A PHP script might collect information from a database and output barcodes for your imaginative customer to print, maybe?

Comment: @inhan :- that seems to be right, might be a developer needs to right an application that will connect to the printer aswell, then only it will make sense to generate barcodes

Comment: @user963725 that even makes more sense.

Comment: If a company is doing a promotion, a customer could print a bar coded voucher off and bring it into the store to claim the promotion.

Comment: php is used for more than just websites.

Comment: @Dagon: That doesn't change the fact that you can print a web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have built a couple of websites for stores that sold tickets. We used GD to generate barcodes for things such as lift tickets, movie tickets, airline tickets; pretty much any kind of ticket that needed to belong to a particular person.

The barcodes could be scanned using barcode scanners and then marked as used in a database. The barcodes were used, I guess, like any other barcode, they were just generated using PHP.

Comment: This was something i was looking for, like do actually these barcodes are scannable or not. Thanks for the answer